# Show timestamp of a vote in the tooltip when mousing over it

Tags: feature-request, voting, user-interface, tooltips

Sometimes I come across an old question or answer that I voted on in the past, but I don't clearly remember when (or sometimes even *why*) I voted it up or down. Being able to see the date/time that I cast a vote would help me remember my mindset at the time.

When mousing over the toggled vote, the tooltip reads the same as if I hadn't voted, with no further information. For example:

> This answer is useful (click again to undo)

The only way to get the timestamp is if I try to click the vote to undo it and get the locked vote message:

> You last voted on this answer [datetime] Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited

However this requires me to *guess* that the vote is locked - if there *was* an edit since then I'll actually undo the vote and erase the info I was looking for.

**Feature request:** Please add the vote timestamp to the tooltip when mousing over a cast vote. This is already done with the green acceptance checkmark for example.

Comment: In theory couldn't you go through your own vote history (accessible via your profile)? It's perhaps more time consuming, but it would accomplish roughly the same.

Comment: In theory I could, but without the ability to search that list you're suggesting I do a "full table scan". I'm a person, not a Turing Machine :D

Comment: But you pass the Turing Test so much more elegantly. :P

Answer (score 12):

This would be very helpful.  The system already varies another tooltip based on context, so it should be possible here too.

Here is the tooltip on one of my questions on the "accept" checkmark if I haven't accepted the answer:

[image: click to accept this answer etc]

And here is one on an answer I accepted:

[image: click to undo, plus acceptance timestamp]

The acceptance tooltip tells me when I accepted the answer.  That's actually true for anybody who hovers, but for *me* it also gives me instructions about undoing it.  So the tooltip code knows that it's my vote and modifies the message accordingly.

Appending the "you voted on $date/time" part when mousing over your own vote would be consistent with this.

Answer (score 4):

In [the duplicate question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/361514/show-when-i-voted-for-the-post) I proposed an alternative solution (that was not available when this question was created).

One of the possible implementations would be to show when clicking history button on `/timeline?filter=WithVoteSummaries`
some extra note, e.g.

```
Jul 29 '19 votes daily summary  N/A Up: 4 Down: 1 Bookmark: 2  you voted, you bookmarked
```

I also proposed to show time of my bookmark in the same way.

Please also note that suggested in the change request tooltips do not work well on touch devices (tablets and mobiles)