# View date of my votes on questions and answers

Tags: feature-request, voting

Oftentimes, I search for a solution to a question and land on a link where I have already voted on a question and/or answer. I would find it helpful to see when I put a vote in so that I can tell when I potentially used a particular solution in my project(s).

I am aware of the `votes` tab where I can look for when I voted on a question/answer but there is no easy way of finding a specific question/answer, especially if there are a lot of votes I have given.

Alternatively, it would be nice to have a date of first and/or last visit on a question.

Comment: Quite related: [Show timestamp of a vote in the tooltip when mousing over it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/176503/209901)

Comment: Heh.  I was going to write something about how it'd be useful to have the date in the tooltip, and now I see I already did. :-)

Comment: @fedorqui I think my question is the same as my feature request so this can be closed as a duplicate. I also think the answer you posted is the closest we have right now for that so I'll mark that as the accepted answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you already voted on a post and try to do it again, you'll see a message like:

> You last voted on this question Aug 13 at 22:06. Your vote is now locked in unless this question is edited.

So if a post hasn't been edited since you voted it, you can get that information.

Otherwise, if the post was edited it is not possible to get this information: the vote is unlocked and clicking on a vote button will perform a vote (upvote/downvote or un-upvote/downvote).